# Assets page "An unknown error occurred"

Tags: assets, error-message, plugin-imager

I'm suddenly unable to load my site's assets page. All of my asset sources are local, and loading the main assets page or any source folder or subfolder results in "An unknown error occurred." being displayed. No images are displayed. The assets section of the CP had previously been working fine.

I can still see my assets when uploading an asset within an entry editing screen, though.

The relevant log info (I hope) is below. Seems to be an issue with Imager, which I think was updated recently:

```
2018-12-10 17:04:05 [-][1][-][error][yii\base\UnknownPropertyException] yii\base\UnknownPropertyException: Getting unknown property: aelvan\imager\models\ConfigModel::imgixEnablePurgeElementAction in /path/to/site/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:154

Stack trace:

0 /path/to/site/vendor/aelvan/imager/src/Imager.php(154): yii\base\Component->__get('imgixEnablePurg...')

1 [internal function]: aelvan\imager\Imager->aelvan\imager\{closure}(Object(craft\events\RegisterElementActionsEvent))

2 /path/to/site/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Event.php(310): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(craft\events\RegisterElementActionsEvent))

3 /path/to/site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/Element.php(320): yii\base\Event::trigger('craft\\elements\\...', 'registerActions', Object(craft\events\RegisterElementActionsEvent))

4 /path/to/site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/ElementIndexesController.php(409): craft\base\Element::actions('folder:3')

5 /path/to/site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/ElementIndexesController.php(90): craft\controllers\ElementIndexesController->_availableActions()

6 /path/to/site/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(155): craft\controllers\ElementIndexesController->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))

7 /path/to/site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(104): yii\base\Controller->runAction('get-elements', Array)

8 /path/to/site/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('get-elements', Array)

9 /path/to/site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(282): yii\base\Module->runAction('element-indexes...', Array)

10 /path/to/site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(542): craft\web\Application->runAction('element-indexes...', Array)

11 /path/to/site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(266): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))

12 /path/to/site/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))

13 /path/to/site/web/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()

14 {main}
```

Comment: In your Imager config file, are you providing a value for the setting `imgixEnablePurgeElementAction`? If so, what is it?

Comment: Ah, it was an error in my imager config file. Setting imgixEnablePurgeElementAction back to true fixed it.

Comment: Wonderful, I'll go ahead and add that as answer then in case anyone else lands here from Google etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, sounds like you've got an error in your Imager config (prob an incorrect value set for the [`imgixEnablePurgeElementAction`](https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft#imgixenablepurgeelementaction-bool) option or one of the lines close by).